# Entity Framework Core 5 primary key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, primary-key, ef-core-5.0

I have an existing SQL database with a view `ServersAndServices`.

I have added it to my data model:

```
public class ServersAndServices
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDisp { get; set; }
    public string RoleDesc { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppDesc { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `DbContext`:

```
public class ServersAndServicesContext : DbContext
{
    public ServersAndServicesContext(DbContextOptions<ServersAndServicesContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ServersAndServices> ServersAndServices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServersAndServices>(eb =>
            {
                eb.HasNoKey();
                eb.ToView("ServersAndServices");
            });
    }
}
```

When I got to add a controller (API Controller with actions using Entity Framework Core) I get this error:

> Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'ServersAndServices'
> Primary key not found.

I’ve attempted this also with the `[Keyless]` attribute before the class `ServersAndServices` but the result is the same.

Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here as all the documentation I have seen suggests this the correct way to handle this challenge.  Thank you.

Comment: Add a PK to the table?

Comment: here is documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations hope it helps

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: true - updated the question to reflect this

Comment: This has nothing to do with EF Core. As I understand, this issue is with some VS tooling (add new controller with actions), not sure what actions are they supposed to create. Keyless entity types support quite limited set of "actions", probably not the one this tool is supposed to create.

Comment: check project.cs file and ensure .net  core version is 2.0 or more and in api controller add using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan was correct. The solution here was to just create the controller manually.  Ivan not sure how to mark a comment as the correct answer. Thank you.